# Facebook Sharer doesn't display correct description

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a very simple generate-and-share web app (www.startupgenerator.eu). I'm using classic sharer.php FB tool.

I'm passing a value (c) via QueryString. This is the encrypted phrase that will be displayed as value for meta description and open graph og:description. Moreover; if a value is present in c variable, the og:title will contain a different value.

Anyway, it doesn't work with fb sharer. When a user opens the sharer popup (via clicking the share button on the website; or via direct paste in his timeline), Facebook loads only the standard description and the standard title.
It seems like FB has already cached the values, and doesn't make the request with the "custom" c query string value.

How come? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the correct way to do this: **custom stories** on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/